# Remove bounty if I haven't awarded it yet?

Tags: support, bounty

I created a bounty on this question:

[Sleeping a computer via batch file in Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/145400/sleeping-a-computer-via-batch-file-in-windows-7)

But I meant to award it on a different one. Is there any way I can remove it and post it on the question it was meant for, since I haven't awarded it yet, or is that something only a moderator can do?

Comment: Generally I don't think there's a way to remove a bounty on your own. A moderator may be able to do it, under special circumstances, but bounty rep is not normally refunded except in rare and unusual circumstances. Posting here will likely get the attention of a diamond mod who can answer more definitively. It may even be something that only the devs can do. The fact that you awarded it accidentally is probably a factor that will work in your favor; if you had simply "changed your mind", that is a far less convincing case for having the bounty reversed.

Comment: @allquixotic Ahh, I see. Well I meant to award it on this question, if that helps a mod who comes along: http://superuser.com/questions/651018/how-to-record-screen-while-installing-windows/651020#651020

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bounties once assigned, cannot be removed by most users. Us Diamond Moderators have the option to refund the bounty, but that's something we don't do on a whim...

Comment: Okay, no problem. Thanks!

Comment: @Moses started bounty on the other question. Let me know which answer you wanted to award the bounty

Comment: This one http://superuser.com/a/651020/201262 Thank you!

Comment: @Moses No problem.

Comment: "We Diamond Moderators", not "Us Diamond Moderators".